# Percona/XtraDB insllation + replication setup - tips/guides for Centos 5.2

Tags: mysql, replication, xtradb

I am looking for good articles on how to install and setup Percona's patched server with XtraDB and master/slave replication setup on Centos 5.2 64 bit.

I believe they can be downloaded at http://www.percona.com/mysql/5.1.34-5/RPM/rhel5/?
and is there any good recipes for setting up HA and replication?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The RPMs are best installed by just downloading them into a directory and typing "rpm -i *.rpm".  For help with this, I recommend Percona's forums or mailing lists - forum.percona.com and groups.google.com/group/percona-dev.

For replication there's not anything really new in the Percona patches.  You are best off just looking at the guide in the MySQL manual:

dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html

For HA recipes, you've basically got the choice of MySQL and/or DRBD.  I wrote an article on Percona's mysql performance blog here:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/07/07/is-drbd-the-right-choice-for-me/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

first step: add percona repository using this wikipage: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/installation/yum_repo.html

second step: follow the instructions on this wikipage: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/installation.html

Master/Slave setup is like "normal" MySQL replication.
Setup the Binlog on the master and setup the slave as a slave. I would recommend using this howto: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-database-replication-in-mysql-on-ubuntu-9.10 (you can forget about the install notes as you have already installed the mysql / percona server)

hope this helps :-)